# Changing the color of legend in plot for R

Tags: r, plot, colors, legend, legend-properties

so I am hiving a minor issue here with my graph's legend. I can't seem to get "RCB Class 1,2 or 3" to show as a black dot instead of red. I am new to R and making graphs with R. Please help :) Image and code attached below. Also, if anyone knows how to make the legend font size smaller and how to add more axis tick marks so that it counts by 10s, please let me know.
    [image]
    par(mar = c(6, 5, 5, 10), xpd = TRUE) # par parameters to add space for legend

```
ERPR_plot <-- plot(mint$er_pct,mint$pr_pct,
xlab="ER Staining (%)",
ylab="PR Staining (%)",
xlim=range(0:100),
ylim=range(0:100),
main = "PR Percent Staining vs. ER Percent Staining",
col = ifelse(mint$pcr == 1,'red','black'),
panel.first = grid())
legend("topright", inset = c(- 0.45, 0),   # Create legend outside of plot
   legend = c("pCR","RCB Class 1,2 or 3"),
   pch=1,
   col="red","black")
```

Comment: Do you need `col = c("red", "black"))` instead  of `col = "red", "black")`

Comment: @akrun fixed my problem, again! Thank you a ton! I don't see an option to put a check mark by your comment for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can specify the `col` as a vector by concatenating (`c`) the two colors

```
plot(mint$er_pct,mint$pr_pct,
   xlab="ER Staining (%)",
   ylab="PR Staining (%)",
   xlim=range(0:100),
   ylim=range(0:100),
   main = "PR Percent Staining vs. ER Percent Staining",
   col = ifelse(mint$pcr == 1,'red','black'),
   panel.first = grid())
legend("topright", inset = c(- 0.45, 0),  
   legend = c("pCR","RCB Class 1,2 or 3"),
   pch=1,
   col=c("red","black"))
```